# Hiring a person by surname

Tags: java

Could anyone help me fix the below-attached code? I've written a Java method that hires a person by surname, and what I mean by that is that the value passed in the method should be the last name of an object reference (an object of a class `Employee` which we desire to hire in the company).

However, the program is complaining that the surname cannot be resolved to a type. Now, `getSurname()` is a method of a private instance variable defined in `Employee` which is an abstract class (and a superclass for two subclasses `Worker` and `Officer`, but that's irrelevant to the problem). Anyone willing to give me a hand?

```
public class CompanyArrayList {

    private ArrayList<Employee> arrayList;

    public CompanyArrayList(int employeeNumber) {
        ArrayList<Employee> arrayList = new ArrayList<Employee>(employeeNumber);
    }
    public String hire(Employee employee.getSurname()) { // the object of this class will be generated in the "main" method.
        for (int i = 0; i < employeeNumber; i++) {
            if (!arrayList.contains(employee.getSurname())) {
                arrayList.add(employee);
                return "Hired"; // "return" terminates the execution of the method.
            }
        } // WHY?
    }

    public String fire(Employee employee) {
        for (Employee i : arrayList) {
            if (employee.getSurname().equals(i.getSurname())) {
                arrayList.remove(employee);
                return "Fired"; // returns nothing and terminates the method execution.
            }
        }
        return "The person of the" + employee.getSurname() + " surname doesn't work in the company";
    }
} 

public abstract class Employee { 

    private String surname; 

    private float contract; // contract = workperiod

    public String getSurname() { // Here we're asking about a surname of an employee
        return surname;
    }

    public float getContract() {
        return contract;
    }

    public Employee(String surname, float contract) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.contract = contract;
    }

    public abstract float pay();

    public abstract String group();
}
```

Comment: On which line is this error being reported?

Comment: When you use return statements, the loop checks if other values are true, if none is true, it terminates the loop

Comment: public String hire(Employee employee.getSurname())  - specifically "employee.getSurname()"

Comment: post your main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `String hire(Employee employee.getSurname())` to `String hire(Employee employee)`.

**Edit:**

About the `Employee` that you want to `hire()` by surname (which I've explained you why this is a bad idea) do this:

```
public String hire(Employee employee) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) { // you had employeeNumber instead of arraylist.size() but hire() method does not know anything about that variable
            Employee temp = arraylist.get(i);
            if (temp.getSurname().equals(employee.getSurname)) {
                arrayList.add(employee);
                return "Hired"; // "return" terminates the execution of the method.
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I could do that to get around a problem, and in fact, it's quite a neat solution. Nevertheless, the direction I was assigned (for academic work) was to hire a person by SURNAME (even though, I strictly named the objects with the surname they take in the main method, so it shouldn't cause any confusion).

Comment: @DominikaOpala what I answered above is actually a compiler error. Your code will not compile unless you make that change.

Comment: public static void main(String[]args) {
  
  ArrayList<Employee> company = new ArrayList<Employee>(20);
  
  
  Officer smith = new Officer("Smith", 1.0f, 3000.0f, 0);
  Officer barker = new Officer("Barker", 0.5f, 1500f, 2.0f);
  Worker irving = new Worker("Irving", 1.0f, 750, 45);
  Worker major = new Worker("Major", 0.75f, 600, 60)

  company.hire("Smith");
  company.hire("Barker");
  company.hire("Irving");
  company.hire("Major");
  
 }

Comment: But then you're passing an object parameter into the method, not a String (surname)

Comment: If you just copy paste some code in the comment and expect me to see it, it just gets my eyes dizzy.

Comment: By the way @DominikaOpala you checking by surname will not help you. Imagine the scenario where you want to hire an `Employee` called Dominika Opala and in the company there is allready a person who works there and he is called Jack Opala. Though Dominika Opala is another person he will get rejected (by this programs logic) because a surname Opala allready works in the company. **You should check an employer by id**.

Comment: Okay, thanks a ton! In this case, I just need to alter that piece of code and that's it, right?

Comment: For this part yes. Dont forget in case you found this answer usefull upvote it and if it was indeed a solution then you should mark it as one. @DominikaOpala

Comment: Btw, sorry for pasting the code in the form of a plain text. I am new to StackOverFlow and still haven't found out the right way to add code as a comment. Any hints?

Comment: Yes of course, paste it inside a block of ' ` '  ,`try it yourself`

Comment: The last question, do you, by any chance, know why the program complains on the invocation of the method "hire"?

Comment: I'll check in a minute

Comment: Right now I can't see how are you invoking this method so a I have no idea. Did you passed in an `Employee` object as its parameter?

Comment: `public CompanyArrayList(int employeeNumber) {
  ArrayList<Employee> arrayList = new ArrayList<Employee>(employeeNumber);
 }
 public String hire(Employee employee) { // the object of this class will be generated in the "main" method.
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
   if (!arrayList.contains(employee.getSurname())) {
    arrayList.add(employee);
    return "Hired"; // "return" terminates the execution of the method.
   }
  } return "The person you wish to hire is already working for the company";
 }`

Comment: I want to see when you call this method, not its definition, for example the main method. Could you upload your project to GitHub (or wherever you want) and share a link? Can't help otherwise.

Comment: Can you even compile your code? Because when you first asked the question your code could not be compiled the way it was (means you had syntactical errors).